# Cannot update distro

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I want update my raspbian release to April 2017 release available here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

anyway when I running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

nothing happen, I'm on jessie of course. What can I do?

UPDATE:

output of : `cat /etc/os-release`:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: By nothing happens what exactly do you mean? Is there an error message, is anything outputted at all after running those commands? Can you confirm the Pi is connected to the internet and that it is being adequately powered?

Comment: Yep is adequately powered (original cable), the output is: `0 updated, 0 installed, 0 to remove and 0 not updated`.

Comment: could you try running `cat /etc/os-release` and posting the output of that in your question.

Comment: @DarthVader yes check the update

Comment: I suspect you are running the latest version, could you try running `uname -r`.

Comment: 4.9.30-v7+ is the ouput. When I start the raspberry the splashscreen show february not april

Comment: I suggest running this command: `sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt-get autoremove -y`.

Comment: @DarthVader seems the same stuff, not updated